# HTML not being generated in View's foreach loop using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using AJAX to call an ActionResult and return a list of files. The data is stored in a dictionary object in the model then passed to the view. I have a foreach loop in the view that checks to see if the object is null. If not, it loops through the dictionary and produces table rows for each key/value pair. The problem is, the HTML is never generated and nothing is displayed. Using Firebug I have stepped through the entire process and everything is returned as it should be. Any help finding out why would be appreciated.

The AJAX:

```
function () {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetExpenseReportUploads", "MyExpenseReports")',
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: { DirectoryName: "ER_#=EPR_ID#" },
    success: function() {
        alert("success!");
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetExpenseReportUploads(string DirectoryName)
    {
        ExpenseReport.MVC.Models.MyExpenseReports model = new MyExpenseReports();

        IEnumerable<string> fileArray = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + DirectoryName + "/")).Select(fn => "~/Files/" + DirectoryName + "/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
        //model.EPR_Uploads = Path.GetFileName(fileArray);

        Dictionary<string, string> fileNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string filePath in fileArray)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            fileNames.Add(filePath, fileName);

            model.EPR_Uploads = fileNames;
        }

        model.EPR_Upload_DirectoryName = DirectoryName;

        return View(model);
    }
```

The View:

```
<table>
@if (Model.EPR_Uploads != null)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> upload in Model.EPR_Uploads)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>                                        
                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUpload", "MyExpenseReports", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileId, new { @value = @upload.Value })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EPR_Upload_DirectoryName)
                }
                <input type="submit" id="DeleteUploadBtn" value="Delete File" formaction="@Url.Action("DeleteUpload", "MyExpenseReports", new { FileId = @upload.Value, EPR_ID = "#=EPR_ID#", DirectoryName = Model.EPR_Upload_DirectoryName })" />
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `Html.BeginForm` be outside the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the reply MelanciaUK. I just tried putting it outside the loop, and even tried removing that block of code complete and there is still nothing getting displayed. The funny thing is, if I put any text or code outside of the loop it displays.

Comment: Then your model must be null.

Comment: You question is kind of confusing.  Are you seeing the `<table>` being returned as you expect but it isn't displaying on your page?  Or the ajax response is returning an empty `<table>`?

Comment: Ballbin, yes, I am able to see <table> </table> but nothing in between those tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing server-side processing and client-side processing. If you want the table to be built after your client-side AJAX call, you don't want to use the server-side model (`Model.EPR_Uploads`).

Instead, use a post-load client call to build the HTML. For example:

```
function () {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetExpenseReportUploads", "MyExpenseReports")',
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: { DirectoryName: "ER_#=EPR_ID#" },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#tableId").append("<tr><td>" + data.EPR_Upload_DirectoryName + "</td></tr>";
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

You'll need to change your Controller to return data in JSON so you can properly parse it on the client side.

Hopefully this helps.